# Postgres Trigger error 42601 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION

Tags: postgresql, triggers

So, I'm trying to create a `trigger` that receive some values from the `insert` action, `join` with some tables and then `insert` it's result into another table.

I don't know if the query is too complex for a trigger, but it keeps raising the error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CREATE"
LINE 2: CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TG_PORTFOLIO() RETURNS TRIGGER
```

The code is below, if someone can help me I'd be glad.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TG_PORTFOLIO() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $TG_PORTFOLIO$
    BEGIN
    WITH LV_MONTHLY_REVENUE AS (
        SELECT 
            PTF1.ENTERPRISE_ID, PTF1.MONTHLY_REVENUE_CURRENT
        FROM 
            BETA_PORTFOLIO PTF1
            LEFT JOIN BETA_PORTFOLIO PTF2 
            ON (PTF1.ENTERPRISE_ID = PTF2.ENTERPRISE_ID AND PTF1._ID < PTF2._ID)        
        WHERE 
            PTF2._ID IS NULL
    ),
    LV_MONTHLY_RECURRENCE AS (
        SELECT 
            PTF1.ENTERPRISE_ID, PTF1.MONTHLY_RECURRENCE_CURRENT
        FROM 
            BETA_PORTFOLIO PTF1
            LEFT JOIN BETA_PORTFOLIO PTF2 
            ON (PTF1.ENTERPRISE_ID = PTF2.ENTERPRISE_ID AND PTF1._ID < PTF2._ID)        
        WHERE 
            PTF2._ID IS NULL
    ),
    LV_MONTHLY_COUPON AS (
        SELECT 
            PTF1.ENTERPRISE_ID, PTF1.MONTHLY_COUPON_CURRENT
        FROM 
            BETA_PORTFOLIO PTF1
            LEFT JOIN BETA_PORTFOLIO PTF2 
            ON (PTF1.ENTERPRISE_ID = PTF2.ENTERPRISE_ID AND PTF1._ID < PTF2._ID)        
        WHERE 
            PTF2._ID IS NULL
    ),
    LV_SEATS AS (
        SELECT 
            PTF1.ENTERPRISE_ID, PTF1.SEATS_CURRENT
        FROM 
            BETA_PORTFOLIO PTF1
            LEFT JOIN BETA_PORTFOLIO PTF2 
            ON (PTF1.ENTERPRISE_ID = PTF2.ENTERPRISE_ID AND PTF1._ID < PTF2._ID)        
        WHERE 
            PTF2._ID IS NULL
    )

    INSERT INTO 
        BETA_PORTFOLIO (ENTERPRISE_ID, SUBSCRIPTION_ID, ENTERPRISE_LIFEYCLE_ID, PAYMENT_METHOD, CREATAD_AT, EVENT_TYPE, RECURRENCE_FREQUENCY, PLAN_ID, MONTHLY_REVENUE, MONTHLY_REVENUE_CURRENT, MONTHLY_RECURRENCE, MONTHLY_RECURRENCE_CURRENT, MONTHLY_COUPON, MONTHLY_COUPON_CURRENT, SEATS, SEATS_CURRENT , HAS_COUPON, TEAMS_CORPORATE)

    VALUES ( NEW.ENTERPRISE_ID, NEW.SUBSCRIPTION_ID, NEW.ID, NEW.PAYMENT_METHOD, NEW.CREATED_AT, NEW.EVENT_TYPE, NEW.RECURRENCE_FREQUENCY, NEW.PLAN_ID, 

    /*monthly_revenue*/ 
    (SELECT MONTHLY_FEE_BRL FROM PLANS WHERE ID = NEW.NEW_PLAN_ID), 

    /*monthly_revenue_current*/ 
    (SELECT MONTHLY_FEE_BRL FROM PLANS WHERE ID = NEW.NEW_PLAN_ID) + 
    CASE WHEN 
        (SELECT MONTHLY_REVENUE_CURRENT FROM LV_MONTHLY_REVENUE WHERE ENTERPRISE_ID = NEW.ENTERPRISE_ID) IS NULL THEN 0 
    ELSE
        (SELECT MONTHLY_REVENUE_CURRENT FROM LV_MONTHLY_REVENUE WHERE ENTERPRISE_ID = NEW.ENTERPRISE_ID) 
    END,

    /*monthly_recurrence*/ 
    (SELECT 
        CASE    WHEN NEW.FREQUENCY = 1 THEN PLANS.MONTHLY_FEE_BRL
            WHEN NEW.FREQUENCY = 6 THEN PLANS.SEMIANNUALLY_FEE_BRL
            WHEN NEW.FREQUENCY = 12 THEN PLANS.ANNUALLY_FEE_BRL 
        END 
    FROM 
        PLANS 
    WHERE 
        ID = NEW.NEW_PLAN_ID),

    /*monthly_recurrence_current*/ 
    (SELECT
        CASE    WHEN NEW.FREQUENCY = 1 THEN PLANS.MONTHLY_FEE_BRL
            WHEN NEW.FREQUENCY = 6 THEN PLANS.SEMIANNUALLY_FEE_BRL
            WHEN NEW.FREQUENCY = 12 THEN PLANS.ANNUALLY_FEE_BRL 
        END 
    FROM    
        PLANS 
    WHERE 
        ID = NEW.NEW_PLAN_ID) +

    CASE WHEN 
        (SELECT MONTHLY_RECURRENCE_CURRENT FROM LV_MONTHLY_RECURRENCE WHERE ENTERPRISE_ID = NEW.ENTERPRISE_ID) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE

        (SELECT MONTHLY_RECURRENCE_CURRENT FROM LV_MONTHLY_RECURRENCE WHERE ENTERPRISE_ID = NEW.ENTERPRISE_ID) 
    END,

    /*monthly_coupon*/ 
    (SELECT
    CASE    WHEN SUBSCRIPTIONS.RECURRENCE_FREQUENCY = 1 THEN (PLANS.MONTHLY_FEE_BRL * ((100 - (CASE WHEN COUPON_INSTANCES.PERCENTAGE_OF_DISCOUNT IS NULL OR RECEIPTS.ORIGINAL_AMOUNT - RECEIPTS.DISCOUNTED_AMOUNT = 0 THEN 0 ELSE COUPON_INSTANCES.PERCENTAGE_OF_DISCOUNT END ) )/100))::INTEGER
        WHEN SUBSCRIPTIONS.RECURRENCE_FREQUENCY = 6 THEN (PLANS.SEMIANNUALLY_FEE_BRL * ((100 - (CASE WHEN COUPON_INSTANCES.PERCENTAGE_OF_DISCOUNT IS NULL OR RECEIPTS.ORIGINAL_AMOUNT - RECEIPTS.DISCOUNTED_AMOUNT = 0 THEN 0 ELSE COUPON_INSTANCES.PERCENTAGE_OF_DISCOUNT END ) )/100::FLOAT)/6)::INTEGER
        WHEN SUBSCRIPTIONS.RECURRENCE_FREQUENCY = 12 THEN (PLANS.ANNUALLY_FE8E_BRL *     ((100 - (CASE WHEN COUPON_INSTANCES.PERCENTAGE_OF_DISCOUNT IS NULL OR RECEIPTS.ORIGINAL_AMOUNT - RECEIPTS.DISCOUNTED_AMOUNT = 0 THEN 0 ELSE COUPON_INSTANCES.PERCENTAGE_OF_DISCOUNT END ) )/100::FLOAT)/12)::INTEGER
    END
    FROM SUBSCRIPTIONS
    LEFT JOIN PLANS ON PLANS.ID = SUBSCRIPTIONS.ID 
    LEFT JOIN COUPON_INSTANCES ON COUPON_INSTANCES.SUBSCRIPTION_ID = SUBSCRIPTIONS.ID
    LEFT JOIN RECEIPTS ON RECEIPTS.SUBSCRIPTION_ID = SUBSCRIPTIONS.ID
    WHERE SUBSCRIPTIONS.ID = NEW.NEW_SUBSCRIPTION_ID
    ),

    /*monthly_coupon_current*/ 
    (SELECT
    CASE    WHEN SUBSCRIPTIONS.RECURRENCE_FREQUENCY = 1 THEN (PLANS.MONTHLY_FEE_BRL * ((100 - (CASE WHEN COUPON_INSTANCES.PERCENTAGE_OF_DISCOUNT IS NULL OR RECEIPTS.ORIGINAL_AMOUNT - RECEIPTS.DISCOUNTED_AMOUNT = 0 THEN 0 ELSE COUPON_INSTANCES.PERCENTAGE_OF_DISCOUNT END ) )/100))::INTEGER
        WHEN SUBSCRIPTIONS.RECURRENCE_FREQUENCY = 6 THEN (PLANS.SEMIANNUALLY_FEE_BRL * ((100 - (CASE WHEN COUPON_INSTANCES.PERCENTAGE_OF_DISCOUNT IS NULL OR RECEIPTS.ORIGINAL_AMOUNT - RECEIPTS.DISCOUNTED_AMOUNT = 0 THEN 0 ELSE COUPON_INSTANCES.PERCENTAGE_OF_DISCOUNT END ) )/100::FLOAT)/6)::INTEGER
        WHEN SUBSCRIPTIONS.RECURRENCE_FREQUENCY = 12 THEN (PLANS.ANNUALLY_FE8E_BRL *     ((100 - (CASE WHEN COUPON_INSTANCES.PERCENTAGE_OF_DISCOUNT IS NULL OR RECEIPTS.ORIGINAL_AMOUNT - RECEIPTS.DISCOUNTED_AMOUNT = 0 THEN 0 ELSE COUPON_INSTANCES.PERCENTAGE_OF_DISCOUNT END ) )/100::FLOAT)/12)::INTEGER
    END
    FROM SUBSCRIPTIONS
    LEFT JOIN PLANS ON PLANS.ID = SUBSCRIPTIONS.ID 
    LEFT JOIN COUPON_INSTANCES ON COUPON_INSTANCES.SUBSCRIPTION_ID = SUBSCRIPTIONS.ID
    LEFT JOIN RECEIPTS ON RECEIPTS.SUBSCRIPTION_ID = SUBSCRIPTIONS.ID
    WHERE SUBSCRIPTIONS.ID = NEW.NEW_SUBSCRIPTION_ID
    ) +
    CASE WHEN 
        (SELECT MONTHLY_COUPON_CURRENT FROM LV_MONTHLY_COUPON WHERE ENTERPRISE_ID = NEW.ENTERPRISE_ID) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE

        (SELECT MONTHLY_COUPON_CURRENT FROM LV_MONTHLY_COUPON WHERE ENTERPRISE_ID = NEW.ENTERPRISE_ID) 
    END,

    /*monthly_coupon_current*/ 
    (select max_users from plans where id = new.new_plan_id),

    /*monthly_coupon_current*/ 
    (select max_users from plans where id = new.new_plan_id) +
    CASE WHEN 
        (SELECT SEATS_CURRENT FROM LV_SEATS WHERE ENTERPRISE_ID = NEW.ENTERPRISE_ID) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE

        (SELECT SEATS_CURRENT FROM LV_SEATS WHERE ENTERPRISE_ID = NEW.ENTERPRISE_ID) 
    END,

    /*has_coupon*/ 
    (select case when coupon_instances.subscription_id is null then false else true end
    from coupon_instances 
    where subscription_id = new.new_subscription_id),


    /*teams_corp*/ 
    select case when select (substring(NEW.new_subscription_id::text,1,1))::integer == 7 and select (substring(NEW.previous_subscription_id::text,1,1))::integer == 6
    then true else false end    

    );
    RETURN NULL;
    END;

$tg_portfolio$ language plpgsql;
```

Comment: Try to use dollar-quoting in same case (for now you have `$TG_PORTFOLIO$ ... $tg_portfolio$ language plpgsql;`, try `$TG_PORTFOLIO$ ... $TG_PORTFOLIO$ language plpgsql;`)

Comment: The error message concerns something which is **before** the function declaration (however, you have some problems also in the code, incoherent quotation marks among others).

Comment: Yeah, looks like the statement before this one might be missing a semicolon

Comment: How is it possible the error be after the "create" if the code starts at the "create"? @NickBarnes

Comment: @Julinho: If the code starts at `CREATE`, then why does the error message say "LINE 2"? There's something you're not showing us.